# Verify SAML Response from ADFS

Tags: saml, adfs

I have problems verifying a SAML-response I get form an ADFS Server. I get the response as an url like `CALLBACK_URL?SAMLResponse=ENCODED_XML&Signature=SIGNATURE_VALUE&SigAlg=SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM`while `SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM` is http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256. I managed to decode the response but I am not able to find a way to verify the response using the given signature.

My main problem is that the signature has a very unexpected format. Because of the given signature algorithm I expect the signature to have a length of 32 bytes but what I get when I base64-decode the signature is a string with length 256.

I expect that decoding the signature using base64 is not sufficient. Unfortunately I have not been able to find out what to do next so far. So my question is: What do I have to do to correctly decode the signature to be able to verify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're conflating a hash with a signature.

The signature takes the hash of the message as input and encrypts it with a key. In your case the `SigAlg` parameter indicates that the 32 byte hash of the SAML message is encrypted with (apparently) a 2048 bits RSA private key, possibly using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6931#section-2.3.2 resulting in a 256 byte signature that can be verified with the associated 2048 bits RSA public key of the sender.

Apart from that: I assume your referring to a SAML request rather than a SAML response since the latter must not be sent by using the HTTP redirect binding as written down in the Web Browser SSO Profile specification, page 16: https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf  (top of the page):

> 5. Identity Provider issues  to Service Provider In step 5, the identity provider issues a  message to be delivered by
>    the user agent to the service provider. Either the HTTP POST, or HTTP
>    Artifact binding can be used to transfer the message to the service
>    provider through the user agent. The message may indicate an error, or
>    will include (at least) an authentication assertion. The HTTP Redirect
>    binding MUST NOT be used, as the response will typically exceed the
>    URL length permitted by most user agents.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me!